# Logger won't work in some files

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I have this pydev project which I did in order to learn how to properly use the logger

```
project
..|.src
..|..|.core
..|..|...|__init__.py
..|..|...|classHanger.py
..|..|...|scripts
..|..|.entrypoint.py
..|..|.util.py
..|
..|.cli
..|..|.cliloggertest.py
..|
..|.config
.....|.logger.conf
```

classHangar.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# --*-- encoding: iso-8859-1 --*--

import logging

class SpeakingClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger("%s.%s" % (__name__, "SpeakingClass"))

    def speakingMethod(self):
        self.logger.info("I'm a method from a SpeakingClass instance")
```

scripts.py

```
#!env python
# --*-- encoding: iso-8859-1 --*--

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger("%s.%s" % (__name__, "scripts"))

def anotherRandomMethod():
    logger.info("Now I'm talking from core.scripts.anotherRandomMethod")
```

entrypoint.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# --*-- encoding: iso-8859-1 --*--

import logging

from core.classHangar import SpeakingClass
from core.scripts import anotherRandomMethod

logger = logging.getLogger("%s.%s" % (__name__, "entrypoint"))

def randomMethod():
    logger.info("Now I'm in the entrypoint.randomMethod")

def methodCalledByCli():
    logger.info("Now I'm in the entrypoint.methodCalledByCli")
    randomMethod()
    anotherRandomMethod()
    speaking_object = SpeakingClass()
    speaking_object.speakingMethod()
```

cliloggertest.py

```
#!env python
# --*-- encoding: iso-8859-1 --*--

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../src/')
import os
import logging.config
import util

from entrypoint import methodCalledByCli

def main():

    logging.config.fileConfig(os.path.join(util.getProjectPath(), "config/logger.conf"))
    logger = logging.getLogger("%s.%s" % (__name__, "cli"))

    logger.info("I'm talking from the CLI script")

    return methodCalledByCli()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

and logger.conf

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=syserr

[formatters]
keys=basicformatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=syserr

[handler_syserr]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=basicformatter
args=(sys.stderr,)

[formatter_basicformatter]
format=%(asctime)s  %(levelname)-9s%(name)-35s: %(message)s
datefmt=
```

I should normally get :

```
"I'm talking from the CLI script"
"Now I'm in the entrypoint.methodCalledByCli"
"Now I'm in the entrypoint.randomMethod"
"Now I'm talking from core.scripts.anotherRandomMethod"
"I'm a method from a SpeakingClass instance"
```

but all I'm getting is :

```
"I'm talking from the CLI script"
"I'm a method from a SpeakingClass instance"
```

I don't see why, I requested the logger from logging exactly the same way in cliloggertest.py and the other scripts

ps : I'm lauching cliloggertest.py

## EDIT

As stated by Mikko Ohtamaa it's because of the import order, cli was importing entrypoint and entrypoint is importing scripts, thus script's logger and entrypoint's logger are created BEFORE setting the configuration in CLI

Changing cliloggertest this way solves the problem (set the configuration before ANY non internal python import :

```
#!env python
# --*-- encoding: iso-8859-1 --*--

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '../src/')
import os
import util
import logging.config
logging.config.fileConfig(os.path.join(util.getProjectPath(), "config/logger.conf"))

from entrypoint import methodCalledByCli

def main():

    logger = logging.getLogger("cliloggertest")

    logger.info("I'm talking from the CLI script")

    return methodCalledByCli()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May guess is that this is an order of imports issue and how your application sets up itself.

Some loggers get created before `logging.config.fileConfig()` call, others after the call.

Comment: It is indeed the problem :D

cli is importing entryppoint and entrypoint is importing scripts, thus scripts's logger is created first.

Comment: Configure your logger before running first imports